# Repeating actions with Selenium with a different value each time

Tags: selenium, katalon-studio, webautomation, katalon-recorder

I am new-ish to Selenium, so I use Katalon Automation Recorder through Chrome to quickly draft scripts.

I have a script that makes an account on a website, but I want to make more than one account at a time (using a catchall). Is there a way for Selenium/Katalon to alternate its input from a database of preset emails (CSV sort of thing) or even generate random values in-front of the @domain.com each time the script loops over?

Here is the current state of the script:
[image: katalon script]

Thanks

Comment: What you are talking about is basically Data driven testing. Google it, try it out and then post questions if you have any kind of difficulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Shivan Mishra mentioned, you have to do some data driven testing. In Katalon you can created test data in object repository (See https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/manage-test-data.html)

You can manage your test data in script like following example:

```
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData

def data = findTestData('path/to/your/testdata/in/object repository')

for(int=0;i<data.getRowNumbers();i++){
 def value = data.getValue(1, i)
    // do any action with your value
}
```